# Armature - cannot rotate finger

Tags: rigging, armature, transforms, bones

I have a finger rigged. When I try to rotate the finger back and forth it only moves slightly from side to side. What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

[image: animated gif]

[**.blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33513)

Answer (score 1):

Turn out that there were rotation locks on it.

[image]